# What is the classification algorithm used by Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've created sound classifier build using Keras from some tutorials in the internet. Here is my model code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Dropout, Conv1D, Conv2D, Flatten, Reshape, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((int(input_length / 40), 40), input_shape=(input_length, )))
model.add(Conv1D(8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='y_pred'))

opt = Adam(lr=0.005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
# this controls the batch size, or you can manipulate the tf.data.Dataset objects yourself
BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=False)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=False)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1000, validation_data=validation_dataset, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

My teacher ask me what is algorithm I use for classifying (he said something like K-NN, Naive Bayes, SVM or something like that), and I don't know what I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)